# Leetcode Problem First Unique Character In a string

Tags: string

I am struggling to understand how the leetcode solution for the above problem works. If any help on how the post increment operator is working on the value of the array it would be great.

```
class Solution {
    public int firstUniqChar(String s) {        
        int [] charArr = new int[26];
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
          charArr[s.charAt(i)-'a']++;  
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            if(charArr[s.charAt(i)-'a']==1) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

The problem  link here https://leetcode.com/problems/first-unique-character-in-a-string/submissions/!

Comment: `charArr` is a count of all the letters in the string. The count of all `a`'s is at index 0, the cound of all `b`'s at index 1, ....

Comment: it doesn't help Johnny.  i am struggling on this line charArr[s.charAt(i)-'a']++;  is the post increment increasing the value of the array element by 1?

Comment: OK. I've added an answer to explain it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand there are 26 letters in the English alphabet. So the code creates an array of 26 integers that will hold the count of each letter in the string.

```
int [] charArr = new int[26];
```

The count of all a's will be at index 0, the cound of all b's at index 1, etc. The default value for `int` is `0`, so this gives an array of 26 zeros to start with.

Each letter has two character codes; one for upper case and one for lower case. The function `String.charAt()` returns a `char` but `char` is an integral type so you can do math on it. When doing math on a char, it uses the char code. So for example:

```
char c = 'B';
c -= 'A';
System.out.println((int)c);  // Will print 1 since char code of 'A' = 65, 'B' = 66
```

So this line:

```
charArr[s.charAt(i)-'a']++;
```

Takes the char at `i` and subtracts 'a' from it. The range of lower case codes are `97-122`. Subtracting `'a'` shifts those values to `0-25` - which gives the indexes into the array. (Note this code only checks lower case letters).

After converting the character to an index, it increments the value at that index. So each item in the array represents the character count of the corresponding letter.

For example, the string "aabbee" will give the array `{2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0....0}`